# How to detect empty msmq queue and close wcf service host after that

Tags: wcf, msmq, msmq-wcf

I have windows service which periodically create servicehost with msmq binding.
I want to process all or defined number o messages from msmq and gracefully close the host.
But i cant find simple solution when to close a host or how to detect empty queue and on what event.
Thanks for answer.

Comment: Why do you not want it to run the whole time?